# Remove Facebook Like button from Contact Page on Blogger

Tags: facebook, button, hide, facebook-like

I just added a like button to my blogger, first it didn't work, but now it does,but it shows on all the pages I created on blogger Including the Contact Page http://scheissemag.blogspot.com/p/contact.html, which bothers me and I want to hide it or remove the div. 
For the  button code I use this one : (which I installed after `<div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line2'/>` )

```
    <div>
<div id='fb-root'/>
<script>
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
    e.src = document.location.protocol + &#39;//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&#39;;
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById(&#39;fb-root&#39;).appendChild(e);
    }());

        </script>
        <fb:like action='like' colorscheme='light' expr:href='data:post.url' font='arial' layout='standard' send='false' show_faces='false'/> </div>
```

I tried to remove with the code I found in this website after searching :

```
<div id="fr-root"> (I tired LikeDiv too)
    my div
</div>
<script>
    {
        // Remove the element from the dom
        var Node1 = document.getElementById('likeDiv');
        Node1.removeChild(Node1.childNodes[0]);
    }
</script>
```

But it's always there !

Comment: In your second sample, the div id is `fr-root`, but you're passing `likeDiv` to `getElementById`.  Typo in this post, or typo in your code as well (which could explain the failure)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing it, can you just set its `visible` property to `FALSE`?

Comment: The code has been installed in the main template, It's not shown in the Page Edit option.